# Memory Issues with the AWS IOS SDK while Multipart Upload from iOS Devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using `S3UploadPartRequest` to upload videos to S3 from iOS devices. I'd be uploading videos of size 3-70 MB using Asynchronous Multipart Requests.

I'm Setting the Data of the `S3UploadPartRequest` for Uploading. But it does have a lot of Memory Impacts.

1. The Major issue that I'm facing is that the 5MB Data objects that I set to `S3UploadPartRequest` is not getting released properly. (It is getting released after a long time since the response has been completed).
2. Is setting the Data the proper way, because if I'm uploading 3 Parts in parallel 15 MB would be residing in memory.

Currently I'm using the SDK 1.4.6. Same issue seems to happen with 1.5.0 as well.

**This is how I am uploading:**

I've a NSOperation Subclass and I'll be initiating the following code from the start method

```
// Uploading process will be initiated from the Mainthread
S3UploadPartRequest* upReq = [[S3UploadPartRequest alloc] initWithMultipartUpload:self.s3MultipartUpload];
upReq.partNumber = self.partNumber;


NSData *the_dataToUpload1; // This data will be read from file using a file handle

_partData  = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:the_dataToUpload1];
NSInputStream *stream = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithData:self.partData ];

[self.fileHandle closeFile];

upReq.contentLength = self.partData.length;
//upReq.data = the_dataToUpload;
upReq.stream  =stream;

upReq.contentType = self.client.contentType;
upReq.delegate = self;

self.partUploadReq = upReq;
[[[S3UploadManager sharedS3Uploader] s3Client] uploadPart:self.partUploadReq];
connection = upReq.urlConnection;
[upReq release];
```

Please Advice.

Here is how my dealloc looks like.

```
self.partData = nil;
self.fileHandle = nil;
self.partUploadReq.stream = nil;
self.partUploadReq = nil;
```

Comment: Could you please include your code?  In our testing we have not seen this kind of memory usage, so we'd like to understand if there is something we can improve or help you correct.  Also, please let us know if you are using ARC in your project or not.

Comment: I've added the Code along with the question. The Project is Using ARC, but for this NSOperation subclass I've removed the ARC. As I should mention, that the upload is happening fine with the above code. But on 3G/EDGE I get frequent timeouts. The only issue that I'm getting is regarding the memory consumption.

Comment: NSOperation subclasses are getting deallocated. But the S3UploadPartRequest will be deallocated some time later the upload is completed. !

Comment: Thanks for supplying your code, but I notice you are keeping a reference to the S3UploadPartRequest on the operation.  Just to verify, you are releasing this reference when the operation is dealloc'd?  Also, there is a known issue with uploading over 3G/Edge on iOS versions prior to 6.0 that will cause timeouts.

Comment: Yeah, I'm releasing the request reference in the dealloc. Even before releasing it I even tried setting the stream to nil. It looks like the last release is happening from the AmazonServiceResponse class. Yeah that timeout is related to the packet size right? I'm testing the app on the ipod5 with iOS6.0 on wifi.

Comment: Also some where in the post I saw that we have to retain the reference to the upload request otherwise the "stream has been exhausted" error can happen, but I don't think so as it is already be retained by the sdk.

Comment: A lot of important release logic seems to be missing from your code snippet, and it makes it harder to debug. For example, `_partData` is allocated in this line: `_partData  = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:the_dataToUpload1];`, but it's not been deallocated in your code snippet.

Comment: Sorry, it is a property. I've added my dealloc method also into the Question.

Comment: Are all of your properties `retain` properties? There still seems to be many missing pieces; for example, why do you need to copy `the_dataToUpload1` to `partData`? Why aren't you using `self.partData` to assign the data? Have you tried the [S3TransferManager](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/TxIRFEQTW9XU8G/S3TransferManager-for-iOS-Part-I-Asynchronous-Uploads)?

Comment: With the Transfer Manager, my application was getting Terminated due to extensive consumption of memory. Was getting sigkill- signal 9. This happens when I put several videos onto the queue. (4 videos of each around 70 MB). While profiling the iOS App i saw that the data/stream is getting retained somewhere and was getting released at sometime later. I was calling the transfer manager methods in the background thread and asynchronously.

Comment: Yeah all the properties are retain and the dealloc of the operation is getting called. Setting data directly to the request also produced the same memory issue, that is why i was checking with the streams.